# which MAKE or which MAKES (difficult one)

Tags: grammaticality

Sentence:  "I admire teachers who are knowledgeable and patient, which MAKE/MAKES their students feel confident."

I want to emphasize that the CIRCUMSTANCE which is created by teachers that are knowledgeable and patient creates an environment where students feel confident.  Therefore this is a circumstance "...which MAKES students feel..."

However, "teachers" is plural and on top that there are two subjects separated by "and" (knowledgeable and patient) so it would seem I need to say "which MAKE their students feel confident."  However, this sounds very wrong as a native English speaker.

I must be missing something.  Does anyone have any clarification?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there is ambiguity as to what “which” refers to, rewrite it to remove that ambiguity.  “... they make their students...”  or “... and who are patient, both of which make their students...”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antecedent of the relative pronoun *which* is generally a noun or pronoun. The problem with your sentence is that you make *which* refer to the adjectives *knowledgeable and patient*. This does not work.

To rectify the problem, you could include a noun antecedent. The issue of *makes* or *make* then resolves itself because the grammatical number of the antecedent determines the number of the verb. For example:

> - I admire teachers who are knowledgeable and patient, *qualities* which
>     *make* their students feel confident.
> - I admire teachers who are knowledgeable and patient, thereby creating
>     an *environment* which *makes* their students feel confident.